# Are files created in Chrome OS developer mode tracked by Google?

Tags: operating-systems, chrome, file-system

If I enable [developer mode](https://sites.google.com/site/chromeoswikisite/home/what-s-new-in-dev-and-beta/developer-mode), then open a shell and create `/some/directory/temp.txt`, it is invisible to **me** through the [Chrome Filesystem API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/fileBrowserHandler). But does this mean that it's also invisible to Chrome OS itself?

*This is a follow-up to [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52719/does-the-file-browser-in-chrome-os-send-data-across-the-network).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking two different questions here, so I shall address each:

### Is a file I save in dev mode tracked by Google?

Yes, yes it is, Google doesn't really respect privacy, even if they say they do, and if you are in developer mode, you are a far more interesting target for tracking.

### Is it invisible to Chrome OS if I save files in dev mode?

No, again - everything is visible, this is configurable in the settings (think of Windows OS with the hidden files option).

On a side note, a file is never truly "invisible" to an OS, there is always a way to make invisible files visible.